# To build or not to build a binary after Offlline compilation in OpenCL

Tags: compilation, binary, opencl, offline

According to [this][1] manual,

[1]:

> in order to change the method of compilation from online to offline, the > following steps are followed:
>   1.Read the kernel as a binary
>   2. Change `clCreateProgramWithSource()` to `clCreateProgramWithBinary()`
>   3. Get rid of `clBuildProgram()`

My problem is about the third point. I have a function `create_binary_kernel` that creates and (supposedly) builds it too, so that I can use it latter. Like:

```
program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context,1,(const char **) 
&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &err);

clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL);
FILE *f;
char *binary;
    size_t binary_size;

clGetProgramInfo(program, CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES, sizeof(size_t), &binary_size, NULL);
 binary = malloc(binary_size);
clGetProgramInfo(program, CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES, binary_size, &binary, NULL);
f = fopen(BIN_PATH, "w");
fwrite(binary, binary_size, 1, f);
fclose(f);
```

Then, another function `exec_kernel()` creates the program from binary

```
program = clCreateProgramWithBinary(
                                    context, 1, &device, (const size_t *)&binary_size,
                                    (const unsigned char **)&binary_buf, &binary_status, &err
                                    );
```

But after the latter line, the reference says I do not need to use `clBuildProgram()`, but If i don't, it doesn't work at all. Building it every time is costing too much time. Any help would be really appreciated.

https://www.fixstars.com/en/opencl/book/OpenCLProgrammingBook/online-offline-compilation/

Answer (score 2):

According to [OpenCL specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf#page=138):

> OpenCL allows program executables to be built using the source or the
>   binary. **clBuildProgram** must be called for program created using either
>   **clCreateProgramWithSource** or **clCreateProgramWithBinary** to build the
>   program executable for one or more devices associated with program.

So the book you are following is wrong in this regards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Too bad, i seems a good reference book. So, ¿Is there a way to _prebuilt_ the program?

Comment: How binaries are handled is implementation specific. Check with your implementer's documentation to see if there's a way to further reduce load times.

Comment: One option you definitely have is to perform the build asynchronously (non-NULL `pfn_notify` argument to `clBuildProgram()`), and to perform other initialisation in your application concurrently.